# What is wrong with my int to hex function?

Tags: c++, integer, hex

why is this code not giving me correct values for large numbers? does it have something to do with me using numbers larger than 32 bits? if so, how do i get my function to accept values of any bit size? would i just overload the function? that seems a bit of a waste of space

```
std::string makehex(unsigned int value, unsigned int size = 2){
    std::string out;
    while (value > 0){
        out = h[value % 16] + out;
        value /= 16;
    }
    while (out.size() < size)
        out = "0" + out;
    return out;
}
```

edit: usage:

```
std::string value = makehex(30, 5);
std::cout << value; // 0001e
```

Comment: Show how the function is called, what it returns and what you would expect it to return.

Comment: wow that's an inefficient way to prepend zeros.

Comment: What is the definition of the `h[]` array?

Comment: oh. its just the hex digits in a char array. terrible way to do it, but c++ makes life annoying. and @Ben Voigt, how should i do it?

Comment: a little patience, I can only answer so fast...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
std::string makehex(T value, const unsigned size = 2 * sizeof(T))
{
    std::string out(size, '0');
    while (value && size){
        out[--size] = "0123456789abcdef"[value & 0x0f];
        value >>= 4;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/v04Vo

Comment: This is of course assuming that you have the & operator overloaded for whatever type T is

Comment: @Dan: Fixed attempt to assign a const reference (I really needed a copy of `value`).  Is that what you were talking about?

Comment: I never understood the appeal of the shortcut `x` to mean “as long as `x` is inequal to zero” … IMHO much (!) more readable as `while (value != 0 and size != 0)` … but whatever. +1

Comment: @Ben I was referring to the fact that you could pass in an arbitrary class type in as the template parameter, and this function would only work (or even compile) if you overloaded the bitwise & operator of that class to give you the integer value of those bits.  not to mention you also need the `>>=` operator overloaded as well, but those are all trivial things, assuming you just have a large integer-type class created

Comment: @calccrypto: That sounds like a separate question, needs some more explanation.  It seems to me like the caller of this function needs to know how big his number is, I just showed you how to handle different sizes without duplicate code for each type.

Comment: @Dan: Using a template is already handy just to handle the built-in integral types from `char` up to `unsigned long long`.  If a `BigInteger` class happens to be compatible, so much the better, but I hope a `BigInteger` has its own implementation, for efficiency's sake.  (My implementation uses bit-shifting which is likely quite slow on a `BigInteger`)

Comment: OK, but what was the problem with the OP's approach?

Comment: @Tomalak: (1) As the question points out, it didn't support numbers larger than `unsigned int`, and overloading it for `unsigned long long` without templates would require code duplication. (2) Creating and destroying lots of little strings, in order to prepend one character at a time.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was trying to hint that your answer would be better if it had included that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this function is done as an exercise, but why not use the `%x` printf format key? itll display the integer value as hex, then you just use  `0n` beforehand where `n` is the number of characters you wish to display, and the `0` indicates it to pad with 0's

EX:

```
std::string makehex(unsigned int value ) {
    char chOut[10];
    sprintf( chOut, "%08x", value );
    return std::string(chOut);
}
```

If you call this with the integer value `14576` it will return the string "000038f0"

Comment: That's still limited to the range of an `int`, or 32-bits (for 8 digits), whichever is less.  There's also "%0*x", where the width is variable and controlled by another argument, but the argument still needs to be an `int`.